# Raspberry PI vid config for use in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, hdmi, tv, raspberrypi

This is another post in the numerous questions of "how to connect ubuntu to my TV".  However, previous answers did not cover my scenario.

SO, to start with, I do not have nVidia / descrete graphics in my laptop (Dell Latitude E6220). I have the Sandybridge Intel chipset.

If I connect my laptop to my TV via HDMI (it is HDMI on laptop to a DVI connector on TV), Ubuntu fails to detect the screen, despite efforts such as rebooting with TV attached and running `xrandr --query`.  xrandr simply returns that the HDMI connection is "disconnected".
At this point, a fair assumption would be to say the HDMI port on laptop or TV is faulty.  Not the case.  I can connect the laptop to a monitor (also HDMI --> DVI) and a signal is present as expected.  I can connect my Raspbery Pi to the TV and a signal is present as expected, ruling out faults at all connection points.  It seems that there is simply something in Ubuntu that can't handle my TV.

So the question is:

What can I look at on the Pi that I can convert to be suitable information for the dell?

It seems odd that a severely stripped down distro can handle the TV (it is an old-ish Phillips "FlatTV" LCD) and a full Ubuntu install can't.

Out of the box utilitues would be preferable, as the pi is not wifi (running wheezy) and my TV has no network connection near by.

many thanks

Comment: Try to run `lspci` on your RPi, then search the HDMI driver on your RPI, look for similar drivers in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at this the wrong way. Your question boils down to How can i use the Raspberry pi "config" on my laptop to get HDMI on my laptop working.  You cant.

The Raspberry pi is one device with ONE hardware configuration. It was built and intended to work with Linux  hence its drivers were well tested and developed for this purpose. Which is not the case with your laptop.

The only thing the raspberry pi can help you with (and it has) is to rule out problems with your TV or your HDMI cable. It works so you know that its on the laptop you need to focus your efforts.

Try making a new concrete question with detailed info about your laptop model hardware and ask about getting HDMI working instead of a leading question like this.

Comment: Actually, my question boiled down to "what information can I use from the configuration on the pi, in relation to ubuntu".  There could be monitor information that I'm not aware of.  I gave info on the laptop - it is stock.